# How to get the value of parameter in condition azure pipelines yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Here's a section of my YAML pipeline:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: appEnv
    default: None
    type: string
    values:
      - None
      - Dev
      - QA
      - Stage
      - Stage2
      - Prod

variables:
  - name: envConfiguration
    ${{ if and(eq('${{parameters.appEnv}}', 'None'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'release/')) }}:
      value: Prod
    ${{ elseif and(eq('${{parameters.appEnv}}', 'None'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'hotfix/')) }}:
      value: Prod
    ${{ elseif and(eq('${{parameters.appEnv}}', 'None'), startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'release/')) }}:
      value: Stage
    ${{ elseif and(eq('${{parameters.appEnv}}', 'None'), startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'hotfix/')) }}:
      value: Stage2
    ${{ elseif eq('${{parameters.appEnv}}', 'None') }}:
      value: Dev
    ${{ else }}:
      value: ${{parameters.appEnv}}
  - name: envFileName
    ${{ if eq(variables.envConfiguration, 'Dev') }}:
      value: .env.dev
    ${{ if eq(variables.envConfiguration, 'QA') }}:
      value: .env.qa
    ${{ if eq(variables.envConfiguration, 'Stage') }}:
      value: .env.stage
    ${{ if eq(variables.envConfiguration, 'Stage2') }}:
      value: .env.stage2
    ${{ if eq(variables.envConfiguration, 'Prod') }}:
      value: .env.prod
```

The problem is that the `envConfiguration` conditions are never honoured. Whenever I create a PR targeting the `release/` branch the value is always `None`. I think it is because of runtime and compile time variables (not sure).

All I want to do is select the correct .env file based on the `appEnv` parameter and the source and target branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax.

`${{ if and(eq('${{parameters.appEnv}}', 'None'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'release/')) }}:`

should be

`${{ if and(eq(parameters.appEnv, 'None'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'release/')) }}:`

As written, it's doing a literal comparison of the values `${{parameters.appEnv}}` and `None`, which will, of course, always be false.

In general, refer to the documentation for examples of correct syntax.